# Maven project creation in Command line

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

Given this Maven plugin invocation:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=YourProjectGroupId 
    -DartifactId=YourProjectName 
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart 
    -DinteractiveMode=false
```

In this command what does exactly `-D` stand for?
I know it's for defining Parameters But Why `-D` why not `-P`
or anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-D` parameters allow you to pass system properties to the underlying JVM.

The Maven plugin can then read these as follows ...

```
System.getProperty("groupId");
System.getProperty("artifactId")
```

So, the use of `-D` just reflects the way that the plugin author chose to get parameters from the invoker (i.e. you).

Rather than inventing a custom mechanism for passing command line inputs from the invoker, the plugin author here has simply chosen to use a standard way of passing 'application properties' to a JVM.

Re this question:

> Why -D why not -P or anything else?

This isn't really a question specific to the Maven plugin since `-D` is defined by the JDK and the [Java properties docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) don't explain why `-D` was chosen.

Comment: _Thanks for the answer_ **Well Explained**

Answer (score 0):

Just from looking on java help in command line:

```
C:\Users\user1>java -help
...
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
...
```